# face detection in flutter using google ml kit

Tags: flutter, firebase, machine-learning

I am working on an application where main screen has a live camera opened automatically.
Here I need faces to be detected.
Am getting confused about how to integrate ML kit.
Do I have to signup with firebase????

I tried working with google ml kit but got too many errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate ML libraries now - Firebase ML and ML Kit. Firebase ML runs on the cloud, and you need to use Firebase for it. You can find the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml).

[ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit), however, runs entirely on the user's device, and it does not require you to use Firebase, unless you want to use custom models.

The easiest way to integrate it into your flutter app would be to use the [google_ml_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit) library, which provides modules for different purposes. For face recognition, you can use [google_mlkit_face_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_face_detection).

Comment: it would be nice if you can provide an easy code for face detection in flutter